# How do I make/edit a land sea mask in NetCDF format?

Tags: netcdf, masking

I have a land-sea mask.nc file where land=1 and sea=0. I want to mask this global LSM to my study area so that the study area=1, and rest=0. I have the study area shapefile and the LSM NC file.

How can I do this? I have been stuck at this step.

Comment: You haven't shown any code, nor indicated what language or tool you are using. If it's python I'd suggest https://regionmask.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ which might do what you're looking for.

Comment: Python or R is fine for me. If I create a mask as the tutorial, it would only have the specific region as the whole mask. However, I want to set my region to value=1, and the rest of the world=0 on a global land sea mask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try rioxarray: https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/clip_geom.html

```py
import rioxarray
import geopandas
from shapely.geometry import mapping

geodf = geopandas.read_file(...)
xds = rioxarray.open_rasterio(...)
clipped = xds.rio.clip(geodf.geometry.apply(mapping), geodf.crs)
```